# Does plugging in a non-storage device to a usb 2.0 or 3.0 port make any difference?

Tags: usb

I know storage device will benefit from faster transfer rates but what about when i plug in a usb keyboard or mouse? what's the difference?

Comment: Depends on the device.  If the device requires the additional power provided by a USB 3.0 connection then it wouldn't function in a USB 2.0.  What is your specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really except you will be using up a fast USB 3 port for a slow device. USB ports are backwards compatible so it will detect if the keyboard/mouse is USB 1.1 or 2.0 and slow itself down to match the device's USB speed.